# Using the Facebook PHP SDK inside a Cake PHP Application

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

**I am looking for advice and guidance on how to use the Facebook PHP SDK inside my Cake PHP application.**

I have read articles (one or 2 on SO) around adding the Facebook PHP SDK as a Vendor Package, but after consulting the Cake Cook Book:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/vendor-packages.html

It appears that support for vendor packages has been removed and that the preferred method is to repackage the functionality as a plugin.

**Can you please advise me on how to do this. Best case would be a working example of how to return data to my Cake PHP application after providing the plugin with some parameters:**

- Method: eg. FQL
- Query: Eg. SELECT  eid, name, description,
  start_time, end_time, location, venue, pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid
  = xyz
- access token: 'App ID | Secret Key'

*Just worth mentioning, I have in the past developed client side jquery plugins that uses the Facebook Javascript SDK. Essentially I am looking to build a server side equivalent of this and implement it inside my CakePHP application*

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using CakePHP 2. Recently i worked on a facebook application using SDK version 5 which uses Namespace . What i did to load the SDK in my controller is , modified the Bootstrap file to include libraries using Namespace .
in /app/Config/bootstrap.php added following code :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    foreach (App::path('Vendor') as $base) {

        $path = $base . str_replace('\\', DS, $class) . '.php';

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            include $path;

            return;

        }

    }

});
```

Then i placed the Facebook Sdk in /app/Vendor/ directory .
I could successfully load the Facebook library in my controller as follows:

```
function login(){
    session_start();
    App::import('Vendor','Facebook',array('file'=>'Facebook'.DS.'Facebook.php'));
    $this->fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'YOUR APP ID',
      'app_secret' => 'APP SECRET',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]); 
    $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes','publish_actions','manage_pages','publish_pages','read_page_mailboxes','pages_show_list','pages_manage_cta']; // optional
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('Your Callback URL', $permissions);

    echo 'Log in with Facebook!';
    exit;
}
```

You can see the same steps in my blog too . [Loading Facebook SDK in CakePHP2](http://www.webguruji.in/programming-language/facebook-php-sdk-in-cakephp2/)

Answer (score 0):

Importing vendor libraries is still supported, the (not very detailed) documentation is about vendor assets (CSS, JS, images, etc).

Assuming the Facebook PHP SDK folder is placed in `/app/Vendor/`, [import the library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files) as described in the Cook Book:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array
(
    'file' => 'facebook-php-sdk' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'facebook.php'
));
```

and then use it as shown in the SDK [examples](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/examples) and [tests](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/tests):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
$response = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT eid, name, description, start_time, end_time, location, venue, pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid = xyz',
));
```